# Flash security question

Tags: flash, security

I've heard that checking a hard-coded password in Flash in a big security no-no since users can decompile the SWF and find the hard coded password. What I'm curious about is if its possible to decompile a SWF, make changes, recompile and then insert back into a web page?

For example:

Say that from within a flash application I pass the current user name to a web-service and get a list of groups that user belongs to.  Based on these groups certain content is displayed.  Basically these steps:

1. Pass user name to a web service.
2. Get list of groups back from web service.
3. Display content based on those groups.

Would it be possible for someone to change that flash app to just display all content regardless of the groups they belong to?  Something like this:

1. Pass user name to a web service.
2. <strike>Get list of groups back
   from web service.</strike>
3. <strike>Display content based on
   those groups.</strike>
4. Display all content

Comment: i could watch the requests made from my browser and access all the raw data. I could then use the raw data and do whatever I want with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would they bother to change the flash app, instead of just querying the web service directly? But yes, someone could change the flash app.

edit: If you're talking about content in the flash app being displayed (not content from the web service), then they could additionally impersonate the web service. SSL/TLS doesn't really help here (the user could just accept the invalid certificate, or load his own CA).

You might be able to make this case work by encrypting the content, and having the web service deliver the relevant encryption keys. Of course, once the key is delivered, the user has it: you can't securely revoke access.

Comment: How would you change a flash app and then use it in a web page?  I've seen similar things done with an HTTP proxy and javascript but I don't see how that could work with a swf?

Comment: Change the link in the HTML? You can do that easily by setting up your own web server, or by having a proxy do it. You could also have a proxy feed your custom .swf at the original URL. But the bigger point is you don't need to. You can just query the web service directly.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I may be misunderstanding, if the web service isn't actually providing the content, but just the list of groups, then see my edit...

Answer (score 0):

With a man-in-the-middle type attack anything is possibe. The way to do this securely is to actually get the content from the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Can they decompile the flash app?  Yes, pretty easily.

After decompiling, can they remove the need to even contact the server to begin with? Yes, again easily.

Can they essentially neuter your flash app such that it will show ALL the content without bothering to get a list of groups from your web service?  Again, easily.

What should you do then?

The flash app should not have all the content embedded in it's code.  Instead, you should let them log in and deliver only the parts to the browser that they are authorized for.